# Kiwi-TCMS, SQL syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RECURSIVE __tree

Tags: kiwi-tcms

SQL syntax - check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RECURSIVE __tree
[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phOdJ.jpg)

```
 mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

I get this error when I create a test plan. Can you please help me take a look?
I'm using latest kiwi-tcms docker image.
Posted error logs are linked below: [enter link description here](https://dpaste.com/CGLNY828D)

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL version seems to be supported. However make sure to disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode which is enabled by default.